# Xcode - I changed the Product Module Name, now auto-complete won't work anymore (when using the new module name)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-project

so I have a project with a name that's annoying to type out all the time, when specifying the "namespace" of a class, like

```
MyAppName.MyClass()
```

So I changed the `Product Module Name` in XCode's `Build Settings` to "Global" so that I can use it like this:

```
Global.MyClass()
```

Everything is working, except that I won't get auto-complete suggestions when typing in `Global.`

It worked before so changing the `Product Module Name` messed something up.

Do you know what I can do to fix auto-complete?

Comment: May seem obvious (or strange I guess), but when having strange problems in Xcode and restarting Xcode doesn't fix it, restart your mac. Usually fixes it for me.

Comment: Just tried but didn't help. Thanks for the tip, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting **xcuserdata** from your xcworkspace. Then clean **Derived Data** and restart XCode.

Comment: Okay, that's strange. It is working everywhere, except when I'm declaring the type of a variable, like `var test: Global.`